# Get Response from HttpWebRequest on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, http-post

I'm trying to do a WebRequest to a site from a Windows Phone Application.
But is vry important for me to also get the response from the server.
Here is my code:

```
            Uri requestUri = new Uri(string.Format("http://localhost:8099/hello/{0}", metodo));
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream,
                                                     httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream, null))
        {
            string xml = "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">Ahri</string>";

            byte[] xmlAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

            await stream.WriteAsync(xmlAsBytes, 0, xmlAsBytes.Length);
        }
```

Unfortunatelly, I have no idea of how I could get the response from the server.
Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks to @max I found the solution and wanted to share it above.
Here is how my code looks like:

```
            string xml = "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">Claor</string>";
        Uri requestUri = new Uri(string.Format("http://localhost:8099/hello/{0}", metodo));
        string responseFromServer = "no response";

        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUri) as HttpWebRequest;
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";



        using (Stream requestStream = await httpWebRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            byte[] xmlAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

            await requestStream.WriteAsync(xmlAsBytes, 0, xmlAsBytes.Length);
        }

        WebResponse webResponse = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

I hope it will help someone in the future.

Comment: We have no idea what your service does, how it looks like. How do you expect us to answer it?

Comment: I suggest you should use `HttpClient` instead `HttpWebRequest`. for that you might need to add an extra Nu-Get Package by Microsoft. It will make your web call easy. For further help, brief your question little more..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is very common question for people new in windows phone app
>   development. There are several sites which gives tutorials for the
>   same but I would want to give small answer here.

In **windows phone 8 xaml/runtime** you can do it by using **HttpWebRequest** or a **WebClient**.

> Basically **WebClient** is a wraper around **HttpWebRequest**.

If you have a small request to make then user HttpWebRequest. It goes like this

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(requestURI) as HttpWebRequest;
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // Do anything with you content. Convert it to xml, json or anything.
}
```

Although this is a get request and i see that you want to do a post request, you have to modify a few steps to achieve that.

[Visit this place for post request.](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2014/05/windowsphone-httpwebrequest-vs.html)

If you want windows phone tutorials, you can go [here. He writes awesome tuts.](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/p/blog-overview.html)

Comment: Thanks @max. Your answer is perfect and solved my problem. You are a life savior!